# How this two sentences are closely related?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046912/synopsis)

> Mark, a writer of crime scenarios, says at one point that,
>   theoretically, he would be able to plan the perfect murder but that it
>   would be impossible to carry out any plan of his because in real life
>   people just do not act according to other people's plans.

In this sentence, Mark is describing people won't cooperate with each other.

In Next Sentence goes like this:

> This is true of Margot, too: Instead of listening to the radio in her
>   bedroom when Tony and Mark are away, she tells her husband of her own
>   plans to go to the cinema that night.

Here Margot just informing her husband about going to cinema.
I didn't understand **this is true of Margot,** how? (here author indirectly telling us above sentence & this sentence connected, how so?)

Answer (score 1):

The author has connected the two sentences by pointing out that

> in real life people just do not act according to other people's plans

and then gives an example of that happening

> Instead of listening to the radio in her bedroom ...*[she has]* her own plans

and her husband then has to spend time convincing her to stay home, which is what he wanted her to do in the first place except that she had changed her mind.